# in Ruby on Rails is it possible to call a method in the middle of several validations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, validation

I'm trying to find out of it's possible to perform a method call that alters the information going into the database for some attributes, during validations. The desired workflow is: user submits a url, I validate it, if it matches the regex, then embedly is called. The embedly function gets the information for the title and image_url. I would like to perform validations on the title and image_url as well, but these don't exist until I've called the embedly method.

Is there a way to:
1. validate the link_url
2. call the embedly method
3. validate the resulting title and image_url attributes?

Any help is appreciated:

```
    class ListLink < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :list
    default_scope -> {order('created_at DESC')}

    #the REGEX urls are matched against
    VALID_URL_REGEX = /\A(http:\/\/|https:\/\/|www|)[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(([0-9]{1,5})?\/.*)?\z/i

    validates :link_url, presence: true,
    format:{with: VALID_URL_REGEX, message: "Please enter a valid url."}
    validates :list_id, presence: true

    #if is a valid url, ping embedly for more information on it
    before_save :embedly

    #is it possible to call just these 2 validations after the :embedly method?
    validates :title, presence: true, length:{minimum: 4, maximum: 200}
    validates :image_url, presence: true


  private
    def embedly
        embedly_api = Embedly::API.new :key => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                :user_agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; mytestapp/1.0; my@email.com)'
        #duplicate the url for use in the embedly API
        url = link_url.dup
        obj = embedly_api.extract :url => url
        #extract and save a title and image element to the database
        self.title = obj[0].title
        self.image_url = obj[0]["images"][0]["url"]
    end
end
```

Comment: I don't think so - i think you'll have to check the format of the url in the embedly method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write a `before_validation` callback which checks your `link_url` and if it's valid (i.e. if it matches the URL), performs your embedly stuff. Then, during the regular validation, you can still add the error message to an invalid `link_url`. This could look something like this:

```
class ListLink < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation :embedly_if_valid

  # the REGEX urls are matched against
  VALID_URL_REGEX = /\A(http:\/\/|https:\/\/|www|)[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(([0-9]{1,5})?\/.*)?\z/i

  validates :link_url, presence: true,
    format:{with: VALID_URL_REGEX, message: "Please enter a valid url."}

  validates :list_id, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true, length:{minimum: 4, maximum: 200}
  validates :image_url, presence: true

  private
  def embedly_if_valid
    embedly if self.link_url =~ VALID_URL_REGEX
  end

  def embedly
    embedly_api = Embedly::API.new :key => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
            :user_agent => 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; mytestapp/1.0; my@email.com)'
    #duplicate the url for use in the embedly API
    url = link_url.dup
    obj = embedly_api.extract :url => url
    #extract and save a title and image element to the database
    self.title = obj[0].title
    self.image_url = obj[0]["images"][0]["url"]
  end    
end
```

Note that you will probably get validation errors for the `title` and `image_url` fields if the `link_url` is not valid. You could probably code around this if it is not desired by setting the `link_url` to `nil` in a `before_validation` hook unless it is valid.

Comment: That does sound like a better approach, thanks for the help:)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `before_save` callback, I suggest doing this in a custom setter for `link_url`, something along the lines of...

```
def link_url=(url)
  if url =~ VALID_URL_REGEX
    super
    embedly
  end
end
```

or, if you're not calling `link_url = ...` do this in a `before_validation` callback.

Comment: May I ask, at what point in the active record objects life cycle does the setter take place? is it before validation? either way, will try it out, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to do it the way you mention here. You seem to have different validations depending on the state of the object.

Instead you could run the `embedly` before save and then validate everything. If you need some validation in order to use the `embedly` method, you could use a [form object (example #3)](http://blog.codeclimate.com/blog/2012/10/17/7-ways-to-decompose-fat-activerecord-models/) to separate the different steps of your flow.

You could also use `before_validation` to run `embedly`, however it makes it that you need to duplicate the validation on the fields required by `embedly` (you need to test it in your method before validation, and then on the model in case you need to re-run the method later). You could get passed it with a custom validation method called explicitely, but I'm not a big fan of this.

Answer (score 0):

I would re-think the design a little. Calling an external service like Embedly is best done as a background job as you never know how long it's going to take, and it could block other requests for your application.

You would have to allow the ListLink to be created without a title and image_url, though. Your background worker would then set these attributes when it runs.

You would still want to validate them at this point, of course, but this can be done using conditional validations. Something like this:

`validates :title, presence: true, length:{minimum: 4, maximum: 200}, unless: :new_record?`

Comment: Ah okay, so you suggest saving the link to the db, then calling embedly and inserting the values it returns? Thanks for the suggestion:)